# Caching parsed document

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

I have a set of YAML files. I would like to cache these files so that as much work as possible is re-used.

Each of these files contains two documents. The first document contains “static” information that will always be interpreted in the same way. The second document contains “dynamic” information that must be reinterpreted every time the file is used. Specifically, it uses a tag-based macro system, and the document must be *constructed* anew each time the file is used. However, the file itself will not change, so the results of *parsing* the entire file could be cached (at a considerable resource savings).

In ruamel.yaml, is there a simple way to parse an entire file into multiple parsed documents, then run construction on each document individually? This would allow me to cache the result of constructing the first “static” document and cache the parse of the second “dynamic” document for later construction.

Example file:

```
---
default_argument: name
...
%YAML 1.2
%TAG ! tag:yaml-macros:yamlmacros.lib.extend,yamlmacros.lib.arguments:
---
!merge
name: !argument name
```

The first document contains metadata that is used (along with other data from elsewhere) in the construction of the second document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to process all YAML documents in a stream completely, you'll have to split up the stream by hand, which is not entirely easy to do in a generic way.

What you need to know is [what a YAML stream can consist of](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2801681):

> zero or more documents. Subsequent documents require some sort of separation marker line. If a document is not terminated by a document end marker line, then the following document must begin with a directives end marker line.

A document end marker line is a line that starts with `...` followed by space/newline and a directives end marker line is `---` followed by space/newline.

The actual production rules are slightly more complicated and "starts with" should ignore the fact that you need to skip any mid-stream byte-order marks.

If you don't have any directives, byte-order-marks and no document-end-markers (and most multi-document YAML streams that I have seen, do not have those), then you can just `data = Path().read()` the multi-document YAML as a string, split using `l = data.split('\n---')` and process only the appropriate element of the resulting list with `YAML().load(l[N])`.

---

I am not sure the following properly handles all cases, but it does handle your multi-doc stream:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml


docs = []
current = ""

state = "EOD"
for line in Path("example.yaml").open():
    if state in ["EOD", "DIR"]:
        if line.startswith("%"):
            state = "DIR"
        else:
            state = "BODY"
        current += line
        continue
    if line.startswith('...') and line[3].isspace():
        state = "EOD"
        docs.append(current)
        current = ""
        continue
    if state == "BODY" and current and line.startswith('---') and line[3].isspace():
        docs.append(current)
        current = ""
        continue
    current += line
if current:
   docs.append(current)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(docs[1])
print(data['name'])
```

which gives:

```
name
```

Comment: Sorry, I normally include full working code in my examples and a generic YAML splitter would be useful. But I broke the distal phalanx of my index finger a few days ago and typing with a splint is "cumbersome" (to put it mildly).

Comment: Unfortunately, there may be directives in both documents. I've updated the question with a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can indeed directly operate the parser internals of ruamel.yaml, it just isn't documented. The following function will parse a YAML string into document nodes:

```py
from ruamel.yaml import SafeLoader

def parse_documents(text):
    loader = SafeLoader(text)
    composer = loader.composer
    while composer.check_node():
        yield composer.get_node()
```

From there, the documents can be individually constructed. In order to solve my problem, something like the following should work:

```py
def process_yaml(text):
    my_constructor = get_my_custom_constructor()

    parsed_documents = list(parse_documents(path.read_text()))
    metadata = my_constructor.construct_document(parsed_documents[0])
    return (metadata, document[1])

cache = {}
def do_the_thing(file_path):
    if file_path not in cache:
        cache[file_path] = process_yaml(Path(file_path).read_text())

    metadata, document = cache[file_path]

    my_constructor = get_my_custom_constructor(metadata)
    return my_constructor.construct_document(document)
```

This way, all of the file IO and parsing is cached, and only the last construction step need be performed each time.